# Display line break in <div> tag from database

Tags: java, jquery, database, line-breaks

I have to display an article from database inside a < div> tag. This article was inserted into database from a textarea. My problem is: i could not display exactly the structure that i inserted from the textarea (including line break)

I tried the below code to replace the enter character to < br> tag but it did not work

```
<div id="tmpId">${f:h(dto.accPassage)}</div>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#tmpId').html($('#tmpId').html().replace(/\n/g, '<br />'));
    })
</script>
```

I wonder if someone could give me some hints to solve this problem.

Thank you very much.

Comment: You should put the language you're using to get it from the database in the tags.

Answer (score 12):

if you want it to be *exactly* as it is in the database, then just render it inside a `<pre>` tag, instead of a `<div>`.

```
<pre id="tmpId">${f:h(dto.accPassage)}</pre>
```

That will preserve the exact formatting in the enclosed text block.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're retrieving it from the DB, why do it client-side and not do the replace as soon as you retrieve the data from your DB ? Not sure what you're using (although that's irrelevant since this can be done in any language) but in PHP, assuming `$output` is your DB result it would be as easy as

```
$output = nl2br($output);
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: PHP has the `nl2br()` function for this reason.

Comment: @FreekOne: is he using php? O.o

Comment: I was addressing FreekOne who gave a solution *if* the language is PHP.

Comment: +1 Agreed Robert, I have updated my answer. Completely forgot about that :)

Comment: @David: I don't know either, I was only assuming for the proof of concept.

Comment: Thank FreekOne and all of you. As i am using Java so the above function could not work. I tried to use dto.accPassage = dto.accPassage.replace(System.getProperty("line.separator"), "< br/>"); inside Java code to convert and it worked correctly. However, in some case i have to format data inside a grid, so if i use java code i have to loop one time before displaying at JSP.

Comment: @tlpd: In that case I'm sorry but I can't help you further as I do not know Java, but maybe it would be a good idea to run a query on the DB -- if possible, of course -- to edit the stuff that's already there, and then modify the form parser so the inserted data would already contain `<br>`s in the future, eliminating the issue alltogether.

Comment: @FreekOne: I appreciated your help. As i tried Lee'way and it worked as what i wanted. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use css to render /n correctly:

```html
<span style="white-space: pre-line">Hi! next line, next line.</span>
```

in your case

```html
<div id="tmpId" style="white-space: pre-line">${f:h(dto.accPassage)}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using java, you could always write something like the following to replace the new lines after you've retrieved the data from database.

```
public static String nl2br(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("\n","<br/>");
}
// usage
nl2br("some\ntext"); //will return "some<br/>text"
```

Comment: Thank mmhan, as i tried your way but it did not work. however, if i use return s.replaceAll(System.getProperty("line.separator"),"<br/>");, it will work like a charm

Answer (score -1):

Give `<br>` without the ending slash.

Comment: If he's using XHTML DOCTYPE `<br>` won't validate.